# Font size different in Photoshop to my HTML

Tags: html

I have done some headings for a web page and I have decided to change them to HTML instead of an image however I used the same size of 20pt in Photoshop and it's huge on the website. Is this normal, and is there any way to get them the same size?

I'm a backend developer usually not a frontend developer, this is why I ask.

Comment: you may find informative this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161710/photoshop-mock-up-font-isnt-same-as-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML is not an image and cannot be treated as such. It is supposed to cope with multiple resolutions and screen sizes.

How are you going to handle someone resizing fonts on their browser?

Try different sizes, though using relative sizes and header tags (`<H1>` to `<H6>`) and style them with [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) would be the semantically correct thing to do.

Comment: No however if you insert an image to a webpage is it equivalent to viewing it at 100%? If it is then there is something wrong, as there is no resizing going on, on the image.

Comment: @Dean - that's true, however, then screen readers and search engine bots can't see it either. And if you have a user with bad eye sight, they can't resize the font in order to see things.

Comment: What about the alt tag in for the image? I thought that acted like an alternative to the image which can be read by bots and to the hard of seeing.

Comment: @Dean - It is still better to have text than images. And some images do not translate to text very easily.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set the resolution in Photoshop to 96 dpi for screen or 300 dpi for paper? This would explain the large size.

Read this article: [How to Size Text in CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/)