# Fonts looking different in Photoshop and Browsers

Tags: css, fonts, photoshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Photoshop Mock Up Font isn't same as in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161710/photoshop-mock-up-font-isnt-same-as-in-html)

Hi, 
I have spent last 2 hours looking for a way to make fonts, in my case Arial, look identical to what they  look like in photoshop. I mean I can't use a different font, it must be smooth Arial. While fonts with no anti-aliasing look decent and almost identical in most of the browsers compared to what they look like in photoshop, I can't think of a solution to mimic smooth anti-aliasing (and others as well, but it is not that crucial for them). 
Is there a way?

Comment: The only way is to crop out the text in Photoshop and save it, then put it in as an image. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Photoshop applies different styles of font smoothing. It's configurable in the text editing toolbar, make sure you've turned it off to get the best approximation possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like sIFR or typeface.js.