# CSS font sizing, why it's not consistent

Tags: css, font-size

I work with graphist that do layout in Photoshop, just like everybody out here. I like to know why, palatino font 14pt/20pt is one way at 100% on screen...

and the same exact measurement is way bigger in firefox, after entering the same css info in the WordPress style sheet...

```
#maintext p {
 font-family: "Palatino", "Book Antiqua", serif;
 font-size: 14pt;
 line-height: 20pt;
}
```

Comment: I'm not certain this will help but have you tried using a "reset" stylesheet. Check out http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ for more info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Photoshop Mock Up Font isn't same as in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161710/photoshop-mock-up-font-isnt-same-as-in-html)

Comment: Is it possible to se type as xx%, and still use pt ?

Comment: base on that : http://www.sherriwyche.com/tools/fontconversion.html pt in psd = px in html ?

Comment: @menardmam you can not get the same text style as photoshop in html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Points appear different on Photoshop and on Browsers.
Have a look at below articles:
1) PT difference between Photoshop and browsers: http://www.sherriwyche.com/tools/fontconversion.html

2) PT difference on different browsers:
http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/

Comment: Based on 1) 10pt = 10px the result is closed enough , thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Use 'em' instead of 'pt' go through the below site

```
http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/
```